# twenty eleven single.php

Tags: widgets, single

I am using twenty-eleven theme for my site, I just saw that in single posts page, .i.e single.php, the sidebar is absent,

which means no widgets in single.php page

How do I bring it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write before `<?php get_footer(); ?>`  `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` or `<?php get_sidebar( $your_custom_sidebar ); ?>`

Comment: with your code, sidebar is been displayed but its displayed after the content, this 2011 theme is not meant to have sidebar in single.php page, which means I have to edit the css and make it compatible
:(

Comment: I just found an alternate method, to get the sidebar, its installing a child theme, I have uploaded that theme on my blog, you can download from here
http://webstutorial.com/add-sidebar-twentyeleven-theme/content-management-system-cms

Comment: Child theme would be the correct and better approach, imho.